# Why is "getUserSelectedOutgoingPhoneAccount()" not callable from my telecom manager instance?

Tags: java, android, telecom-manager

So I am trying to set up a system for multiple phones being connected to a device that handles phonecalls. In order to do so, I've been investigating the getUserSelectedOutgoingPhoneAccount() method, which should help me differentiate between the phone making the calls and the rest of the phones that are connected.

However, when I try to use that method with my instance of a Telecom Manager, it does not appear in the list of callable methods. I can see things like "getDefaultOutgoingPhoneAccount()" and "getCallCapablePhoneAccounts()", but nothing about getting or setting the user's selection. According to the android documentation, it's public and callable from a Telecom Manager. This manager is already set up in such a way that it can make phonecalls and such just fine, so I assumed this method would appear.

EDIT: This is how the telecom manager is initially defined; could this be why I'm not able to use the method in question?

[image: telecom manager definition in the code]

[image: Telecom Manager method dropdown missing the method in question]

Should I use a new telecom manager instance? Is it possible I'm missing something else, like an import? The current import for Telecom Manager is "android.telecom.TelecomManager".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

After looking into it some more, it appears my application is running on a lower API Level than this method has been implemented in (Android 8.1.0, which is API Level 27). This method requires API Level 29 or higher in order to call it.